# Individual shape and position of annotations in highcharts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I have figured out how to set the size for an annotation [individually](https://codesandbox.io/s/xjojkpx6qw):

```
          labels: [
            {
              point: {
                x: chart.xAxis[0].max - 0.1,
                y: 50,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
              },
              height: 100,
              shape: "rect",
              text: "test",
              verticalAlign: "bottom"
            }
          ]
```

I would like it to position between 50 and 150. How can I achieve that?

And additionally, I would like the text to be aligned in the center of the box?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the height by using `toPixels` method. You have to also take a `padding` into account. To center the text you can use asynchronous function, because annotations do not exist in load event yet.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const chart = this;
        const height =
          chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(50) - chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(150);

        chart.addAnnotation({
          labels: [
            {
              point: {
                x: chart.xAxis[0].max - 0.1,
                y: 150,
                xAxis: 0,
                yAxis: 0
              },
              y: 0,
              padding: 0,
              height: height,
              shape: "rect",
              text: "test",
              verticalAlign: "top"
            }
          ]
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/qqqkx2zr49

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

Comment: Looks good already. How can I adjust the padding only to the left and right of the text? "width" seems to have no effect.

Comment: Hi Peterhack, you can use `padding`, but you have to include it in the calculations: https://codesandbox.io/s/6nxvppo42n

Comment: Finally, why is the annotation box outside of the plot?: https://codesandbox.io/s/2wj3p98w00